# SpringMVC won't reach controller, throws 404 everytime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

My project structure looks like this -

[image]

web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>SpringWebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pac.test.*" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller -

```
package pac.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm")
public ModelAndView loginRequest() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        <a href="login.htm">Login</a>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

However, after the index loads, clicking on the hyperlink results into a 404 (Resource Not Found) when home.jsp is clearly present in the path. I simply cannot understand what am I doing wrong here. I've double checked all spells etc and paths. It should work, but doesn't!

Spring is not even reaching the Controller class somehow.

Comment: Can you remove that `/` from `(value="/login.htm")` and then check again if that works.

Comment: @PrashantZombade tried. doesn't work. same error page

Comment: Add a `sysout` in `loginRequest() ` to check if it is hitting this controller/method. Or else it is failing to find mapping for `login.htm`.

Comment: It isn't hitting the controller. I am not able to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: @RahulDev Don't you have any `pom.xml` ?

Comment: No, it isn't a maven project. @AvijitBarua

Comment: Have you seen any tutorial on it ?

Comment: @RahulDev in case the issue is not resolved. If possible share the source code with me.

Comment: @RahulDev you didn't give any response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

1. Change `@RequestMapping(value="/login.htm")` to
   `@RequestMapping(value="/login")`
2. Change `<a href="login.htm">Login</a>` to 
   `<a href="/SpringWebApp/login">Login</a>`

Looks like you are providing an incorrect link, hence it's not picked up by your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login.htm")
       public ModelAndView loginRequest() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
    return mv;
}
```

remove ".htm" from "/login.htm" like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login")
       public ModelAndView loginRequest() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
    return mv;
}
```

And correct your hyprelink like this

```
<h2>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.xml` you have't defined `spring-servlet.xml`. So define `spring-servlet.xml` in `web.xml` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>SpringWebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Now write your `spring-servlet.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pac.test" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Write your controller like

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView loginRequest() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

And in `index.jsp` page instead of writing  `<a href="login.htm">Login</a>` rewrite like  `<a href="/SpringWebApp/">Login</a>`